# XD Plugin Develop: list library colors, character style, symbols

Tags: plugins, adobe-xd

I'm try to develop a plugin that list the assets in the assets library.
I didn't find anything about it in the api documentation.
Have you any idea about which classes and method I could use to achieve it?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to show the community what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 3):

As of XD's January 2019 release (XD 15), you can access colors and character styles via the [`assets` module](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/assets.html).

It isn't currently possible to work with the list of symbols shown in the Assets panel, however. You can submit this as a [Feature Request on the developer forums](https://forums.adobexdplatform.com/c/api-feedback/feature-requests). Please include as much detail about your use case as possible when posting an API feature request.